# Using AJAX to get data from CURL external server

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl

Hello I am new to AJAX and CURL. I'm trying to extract data from an API (https://grocerybear.com/) below is the code I have used in JQUERY to access the API;

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://grocerybear.com/getitems",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {"city":"Austin", "product":"eggs", "num_days": 7},
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'key = my key');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Acess-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    }
});
```

after running the code I get the following error in my console;

[image: Error Code]

ok I updated my code to the following:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "https://grocerybear.com/getitems",
ContentType: "application/json",
dataType: 'jsonp',
data: {"city":"Austin", "product":"eggs", "num_days": 7},
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'key = mykey');
}
```

});

and now I get the following error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)

Comment: Something after this in the script is causing the AJAX request to be aborted.

Comment: FYI, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a header that the *server* sends, not a request header sent from the browser.

Comment: To set the Content-Type request header, you can use the `contentType:` option to `$.ajax`. But if you want to send JSON, you have to call `JSON.stringify()` yourself, `$.ajax` only knows how to send URL-encoded data.